# How to access all elements of a list sequentially in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have the following data in a list (read from JSON output):

```
ecm_data.json.issues[0].key
ecm_data.json.issues[0].fields.customfield_12002.value
ecm_data.json.issues[0].fields.customfield_12911.displayName
ecm_data.json.issues[1].key
ecm_data.json.issues[1].fields.customfield_12002.value
ecm_data.json.issues[1].fields.customfield_12911.displayName
...etc where the length of ecm_data.json.issues is an unknown length.
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
- name: Get number of ECM issues
  set_fact:
    issues: "{{ecm_data.json.issues|length - 1}}"

- name: Show ECM value for issue
  include_role:
    name: set_from_ecm
    tasks_from: ecm_get
  with_sequence: start=0 end="{{issues}}"
```

In my role file "roles/set_from_ecm/tasks/ecm_get.yml", I have this:

```
- name: Set facts
  set_fact:
    key: "{{ecm_data.json.issues[{{item}}].key}}"
    cust: "{{ecm_data.json.issues[{{item}}].fields.customfield_12911.displayName}}"
    env: "{{ecm_data.json.issues[{{item}}].fields.customfield_12002.value}}"

- name: Show values for ECM issue
  debug:
    msg: "Key: {{key}} Customer: {{cust}} Environment: {{env}}"
```

The problem, of course, is that you can't put "[{{item}}]" within the another Jinja template.  How do I access each element of the JSON list sequentially?

I am using Ansible 2.9.

Comment: [moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names) => `"{{ ecm_data.json.issues[item].key }}"` But why don't you simply loop on `{{ ecm_data.json.issues }}"`. The equivalent data would then be `{{ item.key}}`. No need to calculate length and create a range.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was overthinking the problem and not letting Ansible handle it for me.  This is the solution:

```
- name: Show ECM value for issue
  include_role:
    name: set_from_ecm
    tasks_from: ecm_get
  with_items:
    - "{{ecm_data.json.issues}}"
```

And in my role file "roles/set_from_ecm/tasks/ecm_get.yml", this:

```
- name: Show values for ECM issue
  debug:
    msg: "Key: {{item.key}} Customer: {{item.fields.customfield_12911.displayName}} Environment: {{item.fields.customfield_12002.value}}"
```